# Shall we use alise name in update query in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Update table1 t1
set t1. col1='op'
where t1.col2 in (select t2.col2 from table2 t2 where t1.col3 = t2.col3) ;
```

The above query is working in Oracle but not in SQL server.

> Throwing error: incorrect syntax near t1.

Comment: Oddly, @Amirhossein SQL Server doesn't care about things like that., Check out this "funky" formatted, for example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3de5a10286c0658360001b0c9dc6423d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set an alias in the `UPDATE` clause in SQL Server. The correct syntax would be to drop the alias or alias the object in the `FROM`:

```
--Without Alias
UPDATE table1
SET col1 = 'op'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table2 AS T2
              WHERE T2.col3 = table1.col3
                AND T2.col2 = table1.col2);
--FROM and JOIN
UPDATE T1
SET col1 = 'op'
FROM Table1 AS T1
     JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col2
                      AND T1.Col3 = T2.Col3;

--With Aliases
UPDATE T1
SET col1 = 'op'
FROM Table1 AS T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table2 AS T2
              WHERE T2.col3 = table1.col3
                AND T2.col2 = table1.col2);
```

Comment: You're welcome, @RamyaM. Please do mark it as the solution if so, so that future readers know it was helpful. Also, you get reputation for marking an answer as a solution, which really helps you get those initial privileges that makes SO easier to use (such as commenting on questions other than your own). Thanks.